# Show only file names starting with the given string in emacs history

Tags: completion, history, recentf

When using `C-x C-F` to open a file, pressing <kbd>⇧</kbd> (up arrow) will iterate over the files I have recently opened. I believe the relevant lines from my `~/.emacs` file are:

```
(require 'recentf)
(recentf-mode 1)
(setq recentf-max-menu-items 50)
```

In any case, removing those lines empties my history (although the <kbd>⇧</kbd> is still there, it complains about no items in history). If those are not the correct lines, you can see my entire `.emacs` file [here](http://pastebin.com/9mtXFqdB).

How can I configure this so that if, after `C-x C-F`, I type `foo` and press <kbd>⇧</kbd>, only those files in my history whose name starts with `foo` are displayed. In *nix shells, this can be done by adding the following lines to `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

How can I get emacs to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `previous-complete-history-element` and `next-complete-history-element`

To map to the Up and Down keys, use:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map (kbd "<up>") 'previous-complete-history-element)
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map (kbd "<down>") 'next-complete-history-element)
```